# Rest request gives 400 bad request when Hibernate4Module use in Spring 4.0.8.RELEASE + Hibernate 4.3.7.Final + 2.3.0 com.fasterxml.jackson

Tags: java, rest, jackson, spring-4, hibernate-4.x

I have a below controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getOptimizeLoggerByCP/{cpId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody DataTablesResponse<MessageLogger> getOptimizeLoggerByCP(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable String cpId,@RequestBody String json) {
        }
}
```

I also write below message-converters for not loading hibernate lazy objects

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper">
                    <bean class="com.gridscape.ocppserver.dao.impl.HibernateAwareObjectMapper" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

public class HibernateAwareObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public HibernateAwareObjectMapper() {
        Hibernate4Module hm = new Hibernate4Module();
        registerModule(hm);
    }
}
```

When i remove the message-converters from the applicationContext.xml ,Controller works but when i add the message-converters, controller stop working as when i request the controller i got 400 bad request .I call with below details from the rest client

```
url:- getOptimizeLoggerByCP/REE001
method:- POST
Content-Type:- application/json
Body:-{
    "start": 1,
    "length": 1,
    "draw": 1
}
```

Comment: Spring issues a `400` when jackson can't map between the submitted data and the `@RequestBody` parameter. You probably need to map up your json body to actual objects rather than a `String`.

Comment: Then why it works when i remove the message-converters

Comment: Probably because the hibernate module doesn't want to create a string from an object with 3 fields. Test mapping to a class which actually corresponds with the data you are sending.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:- I replace `@RequestBody String json` to actual object that corresponds to String json i.e `@RequestBody DataTablesRequest<MessageLogger> dataTableRequest`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getOptimizeLoggerByCP/{cpId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody DataTablesResponse<MessageLogger> getOptimizeLoggerByCP(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable String cpId,@RequestBody DataTablesRequest<MessageLogger> dataTableRequest) {
        }
```

But still i need to find out how to use  @RequestBody String json